# Configure ctags to show also the imports in go source file

Tags: go, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm using [exeburent-ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) for tagging my go source files. By default ctags is not showing import statements in my go files. How to configure ctags to display also the import statements in the file. 
I'm using latest version of ctags in linux. So it has default support for go lang. I need to override the ctags configuration.

Answer (score 3):

First, I recommend using an editor that supports `gocode` (SublimeText + Gosublime, Atom + go-plus, vim + vim-go to name a few).

If you really want ctags, check [gotags](https://github.com/jstemmer/gotags).

Comment: I'm currently using sublime editor. But separately i need print the outline of go files separately. So i'm using ctags -x filename.go command. But the thing is i'm not provided with all the imports i used in the file. So i need to configure it to provide import statements too. gotags is not printing outline when there is an error in code. So i'm comfortable with ctags.

Answer (score 0):

Go version 1.1 or higher is required. Install or update gotags using the go get command:

```
go get -u github.com/jstemmer/gotags
```

or

```
brew install gotags
```

the commands for generating tags is :

```
gotags -R *.go >> tags
```

you have to use an editor that support catgs personnaly i use vim+tagbar

and there is the configuration that i use for tagbar in my  .vimrc :

let g:tagbar_type_go = {
    \ 'ctagstype' : 'go',
    \ 'kinds'     : [
        \ 'p:package',
        \ 'i:imports:1',
        \ 'c:constants',
        \ 'v:variables',
        \ 't:types',
        \ 'n:interfaces',
        \ 'w:fields',
        \ 'e:embedded',
        \ 'm:methods',
        \ 'r:constructor',
        \ 'f:functions'
    \ ],
    \ 'sro' : '.',
    \ 'kind2scope' : {
        \ 't' : 'ctype',
        \ 'n' : 'ntype'
    \ },
    \ 'scope2kind' : {
        \ 'ctype' : 't',
        \ 'ntype' : 'n'
    \ },
    \ 'ctagsbin'  : 'gotags',
    \ 'ctagsargs' : '-sort -silent'
\ }

[image]